# Need GestureDetector to handle one-point gestures and InteractiveViewer to handle two-point gestures?

Tags: flutter

I need to build a one-finger free-hand drawing tool that supports two-finger pinch zooming and two-finger panning. So a user can one-finger draw and two-finger zoom and pan without changing tools.

Below is a skeleton app that shows my `GestureDetector` and `InteractiveViewer`. The problem is two-finger gestures aren't reaching the `InteractiveViewer`.

My code uses the `Pan` gestures to draw, which is a common pattern I'm seeing in similar Flutter drawing demos because Pan has a `onPanUpdate` that gives the pointer location. I'd prefer using something akin to `onTapDown`, `onTapUpdate`, and `onTapUp` but `onTapDown` doesn't have a `details` value and there is no `onTapUpdate`.

I'm thinking I need a custom `RawGestureDetector` that uses `ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer`. Is that true or is there a simpler approach?

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(
          onPanStart: (details) {
            debugPrint('Start one-finger freehand drawing');
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            debugPrint('Update one-finger freehand drawing');
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            debugPrint('End one-finger freehand drawing');
          },
          // If two-fingers, pan and pinch-zoom
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```